# Add points to a prefab in Unity

Tags: unity

I have a prefab that looks like this:

[image: unity prefab]

I have created a couple of 'points' in the Hierarchy using 'Create Element' and I would like to attach them to the prefab, however drag and drop over doesn't work. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

It is a little unclear what you are trying to do. If those points you created are empty GameObjects and you want them to be child objects of the prefab then you simply drag the prefab into your scene and then child your points under the prefab. Then all you have to do is hit the apply button in the inspector on the prefab parent and those points will then be part of the prefab. You can then delete the prefab from your scene as it is already saved in  your prefab file.
If you want to drag your points into a script on your prefab, I don't believe that is possible. You will have to find another way in your script to find the points without using the inspector, ie. using findGameObjectsWithTag().
Hope this answered your question.  :)